# Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

use gradle to build spring cloud bus client,build.gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: "spring-boot"

    ext {
      springCloudConfigVersion = "1.0.2.RELEASE"
      springCloudStarterVersion = "1.0.2.RELEASE"
    }

    dependencyManagement {
      imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config:${springCloudConfigVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:${springCloudStarterVersion}"
      }
    }

    dependencies {
      compile(project(":video-service:video-service-api"))
      compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
      compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
      compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
      compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter")
      compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
      compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp")
      testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    }
```

When i use spring-cloud-bus,I got problem:

```
o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

config server  application.yml :

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: ${MONGODB_URL:mongodb://localhost:27017/stores}
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: ${RABBITMQ_URL:amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672}
    virtual-host: /
```

http://localhost:15672/#/

```
Protocol    Bound to    Port
amqp    127.0.0.1   5672
clustering  ::  25672
mqtt    ::  1883
stomp   ::  61613
```

what's wrong,please help me.

Comment: Not enough information. What are your rabbitmq settings and is rabbitmq running?

Comment: yes,I reedit question

Comment: It's a connection refused, so your settings are wrong. Localhost vs 127.0.0.1? I'm no rabbit expert.

Comment: thanks very much,it's ok.and other problem: how can i config eureka-server with config-server,only can config eureka-client,now